# Is SSL required to accept payments via PayPal in Magento?

Tags: magento, ssl, paypal, magento-1.9.1

I'm about to activate online payment in Magento based store and i'm interested in whether it is possible to accept payments via PayPal without SSL installed?

Comment: you can disable the SSL activation in `system > configuration > payment method > paypal > Enable SSL verification`

Comment: So SSL is not required for using PayPal?

Comment: yes, it's not mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable **SSL** verification for PayPal through admin panel.
 `system > configuration > payment method > paypal > Enable SSL verification`

You can set this to no.

> So the SSL verification is not mandatory for PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal (as with SagePay) are upgrading the SSL certificates they use to secure their websites and API endpoints.  This will affect anyone using PayPals IPN service especially as they will be removing support for HTTP postbacks and requiring HTTPS postback, effectively meaning you will need SSL to ensure that HTTPS is being used when posting a message to PayPals IPN service for verification.

It may be the case that it is still not required if you are not using the IPN service, however, I would recommend using an SSL if you are taking payments regardless of whether you need to or not due to the changes at PayPal.